# Weird Spritekit Collision Bug depending on SKSpriteNode position

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, collision

I'm having a weird `Spritekit` issue where my moving `SKSpriteNode` is passing through a fixed `SKSpriteNode` depending on the position of the fixed `SKSpriteNode`.

**UPDATE:** Code works in simulator but not on real device.

Example:

Placing my bin `SKSpriteNode` at position x: -500, y: 100 works fine and my moving `SKSpriteNode` collides as expected.

Placing my bin `SKSpriteNode` at position x: -600, y: 100 DOES NOT work and my moving `SKSpriteNode` DOES NOT collide with the bin.

Using `view.showsPhysics = true` shows that there is physics bodies in both cases.

[image: Screenshot from real device showing physics bodies]

x values between -500 and -508 work as expected. All other values I have tried did not work.

Collisions with my other fixed `SKSpriteNodes` work as expected.

```
enum CollisionTypes: UInt32 {
    case Plane = 1
    case FloorAndRoof = 2
    case OtherObject = 4
    case FinishPoint = 8
}
```

Code to create levels

```
func createLevel(level: Int) {
    switch level {
    case 1:
        createFloor()
        createRoof()
        createTable(position: CGPoint(x: 750, y: 150))
        createCeilingFan(position: CGPoint(x: 750, y: 560))
        createCeilingFan(position: CGPoint(x: 2000, y: 560))
        createWaterDispenser(position: CGPoint(x: 1500, y: 212))
        createBin(position: CGPoint(x: -500, y: 100)) // THIS IS THE PROBLEM LOCATION

        createFinishPoint(position: CGPoint(x: -500, y: 100))
        break
    case 2:
        createFloor()
        createRoof()
        createTable(position: CGPoint(x: 250, y: 150))
        createCeilingFan(position: CGPoint(x: 750, y: 560))
        createCeilingFan(position: CGPoint(x: 2000, y: 560))
        createWaterDispenser(position: CGPoint(x: 1500, y: 212))
        createBin(position: CGPoint(x: -600, y: 100))

        createFinishPoint(position: CGPoint(x: -300, y: 200))
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Moving `SKSpriteNode`

```
func createPlane() {
    plane = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "plane1")
    plane.name = "plane1"
    //plane.position = CGPoint(x: -UIScreen.main.bounds.width + plane.size.width , y: 0)
    plane.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 300)
    plane.zPosition = 1
    //plane.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: plane.texture!, size: plane.texture!.size())
    plane.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: planeTexture, size: planeTexture.size())
    plane.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true
    plane.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = CollisionTypes.Plane.rawValue
    plane.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = CollisionTypes.FloorAndRoof.rawValue | CollisionTypes.OtherObject.rawValue // dont collide with finish point
    plane.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = CollisionTypes.FloorAndRoof.rawValue | CollisionTypes.OtherObject.rawValue | CollisionTypes.FinishPoint.rawValue
    plane.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    plane.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    plane.physicsBody?.friction = 1
    plane.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
    plane.physicsBody?.mass = 0.1  // customise for different planes
    plane.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 1
    plane.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0.2 // customise for different planes
    liftFactor = 0.1 // customise for different planes
    addChild(plane)

    flightMode = 4 // dead, should drop to floor and change to mode 0 when at rest
    //print(flightMode)
}
```

Bin `SKSpriteNode` that moving Plane should collide with.

```
func createBin(position: CGPoint) {

    binFront = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "binFront")
    binFront.name = "binFront"
    binFront.setScale(0.15)
    binFront.position = position
    binFront.zPosition = 2 // in front of plane
    addChild(binFront)

    binBack = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "binBack")
    binBack.name = "binBack"
    binBack.setScale(0.15)
    binBack.position = position
    binBack.zPosition = 0 // behind plane
    addChild(binBack)

    binPhysicsBody = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "binPhysicsBody")
    binPhysicsBody.name = "binPhysicsBody"
    binPhysicsBody.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: binPhysicsBody.texture!, size: binPhysicsBody.texture!.size())
    binPhysicsBody.setScale(0.15)
    binPhysicsBody.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    binPhysicsBody.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = CollisionTypes.OtherObject.rawValue
    binPhysicsBody.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = CollisionTypes.Plane.rawValue
    binPhysicsBody.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = CollisionTypes.Plane.rawValue
    binPhysicsBody.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = false
    binPhysicsBody.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    binPhysicsBody.physicsBody?.friction = 1
    binPhysicsBody.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
    binPhysicsBody.physicsBody?.mass = 50
    binPhysicsBody.position = position
    binPhysicsBody.zPosition = 0
    addChild(binPhysicsBody)

}
```

Comment: do you have any images? Olso the collition objects, my suspect is that is colliding with other object

Comment: @SimonePistecchia - Yes, most of my nodes have images.  Also I moved the bin node away from other physics bodies and it still doesn't collide. BUT I just found that the collision DOES work in the simulator but not on my two physical devices.

Comment: is this image from your device?  simulator behaves differently than devices in a lot of situations, so an image from sim is worthless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know the cause of my issue but I got around it by changing the image used to create my physics body. I used a slightly thicker 'wall thickness' on the bin.